# multisite with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Anyone know if there's a combination of packages that can be used together to create a multisite setup with node.js?

A multisite setup would have one code base, possibly one server, serving different tlds from different databases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/vhost/index.js

Comment: I actually needed that myself aswell! Awesome.

Comment: Think https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/vhost/index.js is new location....

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is that you could simply run a number of sites, each on their own ports and use https://github.com/substack/bouncy to route incoming requests to the appropriate site.

You can choose how your sites are started as well. You can start them up as separate executables, or you can create something a bit more dynamic using http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_processes.html#child_process.fork. This would allow you to have a single executable with any number of means of starting up sites, bringing them up or down, gathering statistics from them, whatever.

If you're looking for a straight-up CMS, check out http://calip.so/